# logging debugs in cloud servers/ Integrating Java Logging with any cloud server

Tags: oracle, apache, jakarta-ee, logging, weblogic

I have a Java EE application in an EAR. Application generates logs in WebLogic using java.util.logger.

Application if it is deployed on any vendor's cloud server, it uses their library to generate logs like-**log4j** for apache. Since server keeps changing in cloud, I need to maintain a common technique to generate logs on each server!!

Is there any other API from Java Suite(preferred from Oracle)/ Technique that will serve the need for any server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) which can log using pretty much any logging provider per deployment.